# Why do non regular languages have infinitely many equivalence classes?

Tags: equivalence-relations, regular-language

Let's say I have a language L = {a^nb^m|n != m},

The Myhill-Nerode relation $\equiv_L$ of $L$ is a relation on $\Sigma^*$. It is for words $x,y \in \Sigma^*$ defined by 
$$
  x \equiv_L y \iff \forall z \in \Sigma^*: xz \in L \Leftrightarrow yz \in L
$$

why does it have infinitely many equivalence classes ≡L? How do I show/see that?

Comment: Which equivalence relation are you referring to?

Comment: @Milan sorry I edited the post, ≡L

Comment: Can you *define* the equivalence relation for us?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, sorry again haha, I just understood what you meant,

Comment: The proof of the Myhill-Nerode theorem shows why non-regular languages have infinitely many equivalence classes under that relation. Are you really asking how to show that $\{a^nb^m:n\ne m\}$ has infinitely many equiv. classes?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes I am I just don't really understand how to show that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For each $n$ let $w_n=a^nb$, and show that $n\ne m$, then $w_n\not\equiv_L w_m$.

Comment: If we concatenate the word $z$ = $b^n$, then the words from this class will be in this language, and there are infinitely such many classes. Is that the idea?

Comment: @user270494: Not quite: you really have to look at these words in pairs. Suppose that $n\ne m$. What happens when you concatenate $b^{n-1}$ with $w_n$? What about with $w_m$?

Comment: If $n\ne m$, and you concatenate $b^(n-1)$ with $w_n$, then you get $a^n b^n$ which is not in the language.

Comment: @user270494: And what happens if you concatenate it with $w_m$?

Comment: sorry what is $w_m$?

Comment: @user270494: I defined it in my answer: ‘For **each** $n$ let $w_n=a^nb$’. Therefore $w_m=a^mb$.

Comment: $w_m = a^mb^n$, which is in the language?

Comment: @user270494: Right. So $w_nb^{n-1}\notin L$, while $w_mb^{n-1}\in L$; by definition, then, $w_n\not\equiv w_m$.

Comment: So by proving that $w_n$≢$w_m$, that shows it has infinitely many classes?

Comment: @user270494: Proving that $w_n\not\equiv_L w_m$ whenever $n\ne m$ shows that each $w_n$ is in a different equivalence class from all of the others. Since there are infinitely many of these words $w_n$, there must be infinitely many equivalence classes.